# Difference between traumata and traumas?

Tags: etymology, differences, grammatical-number

Why are there two plural forms of *trauma*? How do *traumas* and *traumata* differ in origin and nature? Is one incorrect?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen/heard "traumata" used anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least hundreds of words with multiple plural forms: *staffs* and *staves*, *dice* and *dies*, *châteaus* and *châteaux*, *pike* and *pikes*, *cows* and *kine*, *millenniums* and *millenia*, *phalanxes* and *phalanges*, *mongooses* and *mongeese*, and so on and so on. The reasons why multiple forms exist, and the cases in which one form is preferred to another, are widely varied.

In the case of *trauma*, the rare form *traumata* reflects Greek pluralization; *trauma* is a third-declension noun with an *-at* stem. There are many such words that were brought into English such as *schema*, *stoma*, *stigma*. But the regular *traumas* also exists.

In very broad terms, the more common the usage, or the more recently it has been popularized, the more likely the Anglicized plural is preferred; the more academic or specialized the usage, the more likely the traditional pluralization will be preferred. Classical pluralizations are also more common in British English than in American English.

Thus, we have *philosophical schemata* but *database schemas*, *radio antennas* but *Formica antennae*, *presidential memorandums* and *royal memoranda*. If you have more than one *cherub* in the sense of a chubby, rosy-cheeked child, you have *cherubs*. If you have more than one *cherub* in the sense of a certain type of four-faced, four-winged angel, you have *cherubim*.

I doubt you will find much use of *traumata* nowadays outside of medical or scientific literature, likewise *blastomata*, *carcinomata*, *hematomata*, *sarcomata*, and many dozens of other words. Before the 1960s, *trauma* was mostly found in medical or psychological literature; since then, its increase in uses and in the innovation of uses has favored the English, rather than the Greek, plural form.

[image: Google NGram showing "traumas" exceeding "traumata" in popularity after the 1960s]

Comment: What is the basis of your saying that classical pluralizations are more common in British English than in American English? I hadn't heard of this.

Comment: @sumelic I thought it was pretty well-established: [formula](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=formulae:eng_us_2012,formulae:eng_gb_2012,formulas:eng_us_2012,formulas:eng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&corpus=15&smoothing=3), [gymnasium](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gymnasiums:eng_us_2012,gymnasiums:eng_gb_2012,gymnasia:eng_us_2012,gymnasia:eng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&corpus=15&smoothing=3), [index](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indexes:eng_us_2012,indexes:eng_gb_2012,indices:eng_us_2012,indices:eng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&corpus=15&smoothing=3), etc.

Comment: Of course, it is a generalization, and as I noted, the more specialized the term, the more conservative the pluralization: [polyhedron](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=polyhedrons%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cpolyhedrons%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cpolyhedra%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cpolyhedra%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Comment: Your mention of "mongeese" sent me to the nearest dictionary to check whether this error has really entered the language. I'm delighted to report that, at least according to this one dictionary, it has not.

Comment: @AndreasBlass *Mongeese* grates on my ears as well, but [so goes the language](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mongoose).

Answer (score 1):

*Traumata* (pronounced "TRAW-muh-tuh") is from the Greek plural; *traumas* was made in English using the English plural suffix *-(e)s.* Neither is incorrect. *Traumata* is not commonly used, or even commonly known, although you can find it in some academic works. A [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=traumas%2C%20traumata&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctraumas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctraumata%3B%2Cc0) chart comparing them suggests *traumas* is more commonly used. But neither of the plural forms is particularly frequent compared to the singular form *trauma*.

There are a number of other words taken from Greek that can be pluralized by changing the *-ma* in the singular form to *-mata,* such as *stigma, schema, lemma, comma, miasma, teratoma.* These words were all neuter in Greek. (Reference: "[Latin and Greek endings / plurals v1.1](http://www.academia.edu/10301228/Latin_and_Greek_endings_plurals_v1.1)," uploaded to academia.edu by Catherine Ebenezer)

Comment: Of course, Google finds 5,900 uses of "commas" here in EL&U, and a whopping 60 of "commata".